# External monitor instability while connected via HDMI

Tags: 20.04, multiple-monitors, hdmi, flicker

Recently I tried using HDMI connection from my laptop to my second screen. I can connect to the screen without any problems, but the connection is very poor. The second screen keeps flickering and keeps turning off and on repeatedly. Second screen goes black for a few seconds, then turns back on. It happens very often (a few times per minute) - so just ignoring it is not an option!

Initially I thought something was wrong with my HDMI port or my HDMI cable, but luckily I still have a windows 10 boot on my laptop. I tried running it on windows and everything works just fine - no flickering and no turning off. This makes me believe my OS is the problem.

I'm running Focal Fossa, aside from that I don't know which information could be useful.

Any ideas on what the problem here is? And more importantly, how to solve it?

Edit: I'm running Ubuntu 20.04, my GPU is nvidia gtx 960M, driver version is 455.38

sudo lshw -c video output:

```
  *-display                 
       description: 3D controller
       product: GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:133 memory:de000000-deffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:df000000-df07ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: HD Graphics 530
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:131 memory:dd000000-ddffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display' output

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. HD Graphics 530
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
--
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M] (rev a2)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

Comment: It would be useful to know the Ubuntu distribution variant and version, and what graphics card you have and what graphics drivers are being installed on your machine. Editing your original question to contain the output of `sudo lshw -c video` would be a good start.

Comment: Output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` edited into your original question could also be useful.

Comment: @Levente Thanks for you answer! I've edited the question to contain the information you asked for.

Comment: I have a `970M` and it's been working perfectly for years. I have different drivers than you though: `Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_384_drm, nvidia_384`

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Same Ubuntu version? I'm using the latest recommended drivers though :/

Comment: Ok, this is the point when I'm getting out of my league, but now you could now start probing around in system logs for error messages that are related to your driver(s). Finding such error messages could forward your case. `dmesg | grep -iE 'i915|nvidia*|nouveau'` could print something interesting. Also see https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/viewing-and-monitoring-log-files#1-overview . I am not great at this part, but I hope others also chime in.

Comment: @Terra Not same version and I don't use the latest nVidia "bleeding-edge" drivers. Once a version of kernel chain works and nvidia works I just stay on it forever. If it ain't broke don't fix it I guess you could say.

Comment: `tail -f` allows real-time monitoring of logs, so maybe watching a console running `tail -f /var/log/syslog` or `tail -f /var/log/gpu-manager.log` while the external monitor shenanigans are happening, might offer further insight?

Comment: also `journalctl -f`